# SSRS migration from 2008 to 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We need to migrate SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2016 which includes:

- All RDL reports
- Subscriptions
- User Access

I cannot find any tool, can someone please help/suggest - We need to migrate everything from 2008 to 2016 server

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no migration tool unfortunately. I did the same process (2008 -> 2016) late last year and below are the notes I made while I was going.

I've replaced my server names with generic names and in my case the old setup had SSRS running on a different server to the database engine so when you see OLD_DB_SERVER_NAME and OLD_SSRS_SERVER_NAME they may actually be the same server in you case.

Hope you find this useful.

[image]

Comment: One question: restoring ssrs 2008 database on ssrs 2016... won't this create any issue?

Comment: No, once restored we changed the compatibility level to SQL Server 2016 and that was it.

Comment: can you share your contact info pls, asking all her will take lot of time.. better to email you...

Comment: Sorry, I can't really do that, I'm not always around and work is getting crazy at the moment so I'll likely be very busy over the next few weeks. I suggest if you have specific questions you post them as new questions in SO detailing what you have done so far and others may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing.. you simply have to open the 2008 report in a new version of report designer or Visual studio and upload it to 2016. This "upgrades" the report. I'm pretty sure you can just upload the 2008 versions to 2016 as well..