# SSRS 2012 is pointing to SQL Server 2008 databases; want to move the reports database to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

SSRS 2012 is pointing to SQL Server 2008 databases with default DB names and in native mode; I want to move the report database to SQL Server 2012.

Is it as easy as backup and restore to a SQL Server 2012 instance and repoint the SSRS to the a new location? Looking for any gotcha's

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar question below... It describes moving from 2008 to 2016 but the process should be very similar for 2012. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876442/ssrs-migration-from-2008-to-2016/46879292#46879292

Comment: Thanks but that is upgrading SSRS, I just want to move the DBs from 2008 to 2012 and seems it is as simple as just backup and restore