# How to migrate an existing SSRS setup to a new server?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have just installed a new SQL Server  instance with SSRS to replace an SQL Server instance. I need to move the SSRS data from the 2012 server to the 2016 server easily. There are several hundred reports with the requisite data sources and data sets. Moving everything one at a time would be a solution, but will take quite a while.

I have tried to backup the 2012 SSRS databases and restore them on the 2016 server, but SSRS server would not start after that. I was forced to restore the original 2016 databases for the reporting server to start.

What else can I do the facilitate the quick transfer of the reports, etc. from the 2012 server to the new server?

Comment: I did a task similar but from SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2016 but I think the process would be almost identical. Check my answer to this question for a quick guide on the migration. It took me a couple of hours from start to finish as I remember...


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876442/ssrs-migration-from-2008-to-2016/46879292#46879292

Comment: @AlanSchofield, thank you. I will be trying this after fighting another fire that just came up with the server migration...

Comment: @AlanSchofield Post this as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: done thanks. Hope you found it useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a task similar but from SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2016 but I think the process would be almost identical. Check my answer to this question for a quick guide on the migration. It took me a couple of hours from start to finish as I remember... [SSRS migration from 2008 to 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876442/ssrs-migration-from-2008-to-2016/46879292#46879292)