# Migrated SSRS Server will not load reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I started this process back in November with this question: [How to migrate an existing SSRS setup to a new server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328234/how-to-migrate-an-existing-ssrs-setup-to-a-new-server)

I was able to migrate everything to the new server without any issues. There were no errors on any of the tabs in the Report Server Configuration Manager. And the Reporting Service started with out errors. I was able navigate the expected "directory" structure through the web interface. However, when I tried to execute a report, upload a report or manage the report I received an error dialog that read "An error has occurred. Something went wrong. Please try again later." This isn't the most helpful error, so I went to the Report Service error log and found this exception in the log:

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!4a!03/02/2019-12:44:39:: e ERROR: [c4tdsgh8]: OData exception occurred: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.ReportingService2010.IsSSLRequired()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetItemDefinition(String itemPath, Byte[] definition, Property[] properties)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapRS2010Proxy.<>c__DisplayClass14.<SetItemDefinition>b__13()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapAuthenticationHelper.ExecuteWithWindowsAuth[TReturn](SoapHttpClientProtocol soapClient, IPrincipal userPrincipal, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapAuthenticationHelper.ExecuteWithCorrespondingAuthMechanism[TReturn](SoapHttpClientProtocol soapClient, IPrincipal userPrincipal, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapRS2010Proxy.SetItemDefinition(IPrincipal userPrincipal, String itemPath, Byte[] definition, Property[] properties)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemRepository.UpdateReport(IPrincipal userPrincipal, String origItemPath, Report item, Boolean renameOrMove, String[] delta)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemRepository.Update(IPrincipal userPrincipal, Guid key, CatalogItem catalogItem, String[] delta)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.ODataWebApi.V1.Controllers.CatalogItemsController.PutEntity(String key, CatalogItem entity)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.ODataWebApi.V1.Controllers.Reflection.EntitySetReflectionODataController`1.Put(ODataPath oDataPath, T value)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext().
```

I spent a few hours looking this error up with no solution. It could be that I was pretty fried and I missed something, but any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Error says:  Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:443   Whatever your report is trying to do/what server and it is trying to access are you sure the ID running the SSRS report has correct permissions?  Also does the server running the SSRS report able to access the server (ports open/firewalls, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find its faster to create a SSRS project in SSDT, import the reports and redeploy them. You may have to recreate the data sources but in my experience this is the fastest way to get it done.