# SSRS error The item '/68f0607b-9378-4bbb-9e70-4da3d7d66838' cannot be found

Tags: reporting-services

I migrated reports from 2008 R2 to 2016 reporting services, and when I open the reporting service Web Portal url or reload it, I get this error: The item '/68f0607b-9378-4bbb-9e70-4da3d7d66838' cannot be found.
The error also appears when I click 'Branding' in the site setting section but I don't have any branding items uploaded to the site. I also checked the catalog table in ReportServer database and there is no any object with this ItemId.
Below is the error message in ssrs log:

Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!library!3!07/27/2021-08:44:45:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/68f0607b-9378-4bbb-9e70-4da3d7d66838' cannot be found.;

Please help!

Comment: You should probably list the steps you carried out when you did the migration. I did a similar migration from 2008 (not R2) a few years ago and listed all the main steps here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876442/ssrs-migration-from-2008-to-2016/46879292#46879292

Answer (score 1):

I've created new report server database using Report Server Configuration Manager. dbo.Catalog table consists of two rows.

**ItemID;Path;Name;ParentID;Type...**

*ID1; ; ;NULL;1...*

*ID2;/68f0607b-9378-4bbb-9e70-4da3d7d66838;System Resources;ID1;1...*

If I delete second row (**Name - System Resources**), I get "The item '/68f0607b-9378-4bbb-9e70-4da3d7d66838' cannot be found." error.

Hope this information will help.

Comment: Ty, I cloned a db line with this info to fix the popup anomaly

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed/deleted your reporting items, you may need to reset manually the starting item from the Report Projects properties page. Right click your report project to open the Properties dialog, and then change the StartItem value.

[image]